# How to configure vcftools in Ubuntu during installation?

Tags: installation, configure, vcftools

I'm trying to install VCFtools (https://github.com/vcftools/vcftools) in my Ubuntu and getting error when trying to configure it.
The readme file recommends:

```
cd vcftools
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

To begin, I dont have a configure file, but a configure.ac. HOWEVER, after running ./autogen.sh, the configure file is created, but I get an error trying to "execute" it.

```
imo@vm-genetica-linux:~/Descargas/vcftools-master$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking for clang++... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/imo/Descargas/vcftools-master':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Seems that I'm missing a lot of pre-requisites. Could anyone help me indicating what exactly I need?

Thank you,

Yasmin